# Why does ggplot2 repeat (unfacet) my data when adding text annotations?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Alright, this has got me stumped.  I have this function:

```
tf <- function(formula = NULL, data = NULL) {
res <- as.character(formula[[2]])
fac2 <- as.character(formula[[3]][3])
fac1 <- as.character(formula[[3]][2])

# Aesthetic & Data 1
p <- ggplot(aes_string(x = fac1, y = res, color = fac1), data = data) +
    facet_grid(paste(".~", fac2)) + geom_point() # OK if we only go this far

facCounts <- count(data, vars = c(fac2, fac1))
facCounts$label <- paste("n = ", facCounts$freq , sep = "")
facCounts$y <- min(data$res) - 0.1*diff(range(data$res))
facCounts <- facCounts[,-3]
names(facCounts) <- c("f2", "f1", "lab", "y") # data frame looks correct

# Aesthetic & Data 2
p <- p + geom_text(aes(x = f1, y = y, label = lab),
        color = "black", size = 4.0, data = facCounts) + facet_grid(".~f2")
p
}
```

Which when run with this data and call:

```
set.seed(1234)
mydf <- data.frame(
    resp = rnorm(40),
    cat1 = sample(LETTERS[1:3], 40, replace = TRUE),
    cat2 = sample(letters[1:2], 40, replace = TRUE))

p <- tf(formula = resp~cat1*cat2, data = mydf); print(p)
```

Produces this picture:

[image]

If you look carefully, you'll see that the data in the two facets are actually the same. The counts are correct for that data that *should* be displayed (and is stored in `facCounts`).  If the call to `geom_text` is commented out, then the plot is correct. A variety of changes to the `geom_text` call leave me with either what you see above, or the correct data is present but the count texts overlap.  I can't find the way out of this labyrinth!  An attempt with `+ annotate("text", ...)` doesn't work either.  What change is needed to keep the data faceted and the counts correct?  Thanks.  This is ggplot 0.9.3 btw.

Comment: You're calling `facet_grid` a second time. Remove it and I think it will work.

Comment: Ah, I see. But that will require renaming `f2` to match the faceting variable in the first data set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that I've convinced myself that this will work:

```
tf <- function(formula = NULL, data = NULL) {
  res <- as.character(formula[[2]])
  fac2 <- as.character(formula[[3]][3])
  fac1 <- as.character(formula[[3]][2])

  # Aesthetic & Data 1
  p <- ggplot(aes_string(x = fac1, y = res, color = fac1), data = data) +
    facet_grid(paste(".~", fac2)) + geom_point() # OK if we only go this far

  facCounts <- count(data, vars = c(fac2, fac1))
  facCounts$label <- paste("n = ", facCounts$freq , sep = "")
  facCounts$y <- min(data$res) - 0.1*diff(range(data$res))
  facCounts <- facCounts[,-3]
  names(facCounts) <- c("cat2", "f1", "lab", "y") # data frame looks correct

  # Aesthetic & Data 2
  p <- p + geom_text(aes(x = f1, y = y, label = lab),
                     color = "black", size = 4.0, data = facCounts)
  p
}
```

You were calling `facet_grid` a second time using a differently named faceting variable. Removing the second call and renaming `f2` to `cat2 seems to work.

Comment: Beautiful!  I had suspected something similar, and experimented with not calling `facet_grid` a second time, and also calling it differently, but did not consider making the variable name correspond to the earlier aesthetic.  Thanks, this has been bugging me all week.